# JavaScript local storage value from Service to Controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am setting a local storage value in a AngularJS Service and trying to get the value in a AngularJS controller. But In the controller, getting null value instead of the value I have set in the service.

**Here is the service where I have set the local storage value:**

```
app.factory('accountService', ['$http', '$q', 'serviceBasePath', 'userService', '$window', function ($http, $q, serviceBasePath, userService, $window) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.login = function (user) {
        var obj = { 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password, 'grant_type': 'password' };
        Object.toparams = function ObjectsToParams(obj) {
            var p = [];
            for (var key in obj) {
                p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
            }
            return p.join('&');
        }

        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: serviceBasePath + "/token",
            data: Object.toparams(obj),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            userService.SetCurrentUser(response.data);

            // The local storage value I have set

            localStorage.setItem('IsAuthenticated', true);
            localStorage.setItem('userName', response.username);

            defer.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (error) {
            defer.reject(error.data);
        })
        return defer.promise;
    }
    fac.logout = function () {
        userService.CurrentUser = null;
        userService.SetCurrentUser(userService.CurrentUser);

    }
    return fac;
}])
```

**Here is the controller where I am trying to get the previously set local storage value:**

```
app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', 'accountService', '$location', '$window', function ($scope, accountService, $location, $window) {

    $scope.message = localStorage.getItem("IsAuthenticated");   
    console.log($scope.message);

    $scope.logout = function () {
        accountService.logout();
        $location.path('/login');
    }

 }])
```

***Problem is I am getting null value instead of the value I have set in the service.***

**Any Help Please!**

Comment: Please check your local storage using chrome debug tool. Is that value is stored on local storage or not

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary. Nobody but you knows what exactly happens there. If it is null, the most reasonable explanation is that the value wasn't set.

Comment: If you never call the "login"... And why, why overload Object? You are using the overload ONLY ONCE!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Best way to deal with browser storage using angular is:

1) Create a service that deals with localStorage, sessionStorage, cookie with generic methods that exposed through service.

2) This service will consumed by controller specific service, this service also handles keys that going to used to store in storage.

3) This service will expose more specific methods that consumed by controller.

eg:

**UserController:**

```
userService.setUserSession(session)
```

**UserService:**

```
var SESSION_KEY = 'userSession';
setUserSession() {
    storageService.sessionStorageProvider.set(SESSION_KEY, session)
}
```

**StorageService:**

```
// here you need to create generic method using inheritance which will expose sessionStorage and loacalStorage and cookieStorage.
```

Comment: This is the best and very "Anguar-way" solution, just make a service for it. This should be marked as solution

Answer (score 0):

First try to get this in factory itself..after setting it...if you are able to get there then surely you will get in controller as well. Because local Storage nothing to relate with factory or controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , Use **$window**.

```
$window.localStorage.setItem('userName', response.username);
```

Comment: There is no difference between $window.localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.setItem() as I am passing the $window service through function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to inject the dependency into your factory:

```
app.factory('accountService', ['$http', '$q', 'serviceBasePath', 'userService', '$window', '$localStorage', function ($http, $q, serviceBasePath, userService, $window, $localStorage) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.login = function (user) {
        var obj = { 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password, 'grant_type': 'password' };
        Object.toparams = function ObjectsToParams(obj) {
            var p = [];
            for (var key in obj) {
                p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
            }
            return p.join('&');
        }

        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: serviceBasePath + "/token",
            data: Object.toparams(obj),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function (response) {
            userService.SetCurrentUser(response.data);

            // The local storage value I have set

            $localStorage.IsAuthenticated = true;
            $localStorage.userName = response.username;

            //localStorage.setItem('IsAuthenticated', true);
            //localStorage.setItem('userName', response.username);

            defer.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (error) {
            defer.reject(error.data);
        })
        return defer.promise;
    }
    fac.logout = function () {
        userService.CurrentUser = null;
        userService.SetCurrentUser(userService.CurrentUser);

    }
    return fac;
}])
```